Python, selenium, how to login on a site
I'm trying to select the text box for the 'Username' and 'Password' on the website:
https://inhuur-ns.my.site.com/vms/s/login/?language=en_US
I saw answers about IFRAMEs but that seems not to be the case here.
I'm using Python 3.12 and Selenium. I've tried with find_name, find_id etc. but without success.
The click button I'm able to use with
login_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@title='Login']")


Given the HTML of the username field,
<input class="slds-input" part="input" lwc-enmikoh2qu="" id="input-10" name="username" placeholder="Username" type="text" aria-describedby="help-message-10" aria-errormessage="help-message-10">

it has a name attribute so you can use a simple CSS selector,
[name='username']

The rest of the code to log in is pretty straightforward also,
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[name='username']"))).send_keys("username")
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[name='password']").send_keys("password")
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[title='Login']").click()


I'm getting a timeout error. When I remove the wait and use only tthe find l'm getting an error: NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element.

Selecting the username
document.evaluate('//input[@name="username"]', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue

For password change username to password.


Found it with the long xpath names. When I use the short names, it's not always working. The input names change sometimes (input-7 becomes input-10 and input-10 becomes input-13):
username_field = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/c-login-page/div/lightning-layout/slot/lightning-layout-item[1]/slot/lightning-input/lightning-primitive-input-simple/div[1]/div/input')

password_field = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/c-login-page/div/lightning-layout/slot/lightning-layout-item[2]/slot/lightning-input/lightning-primitive-input-simple/div[1]/div/input')


Absolute XPaths (ones that start with /html) are NOT the way to go here or really anywhere. They are extremely brittle and will break at the smallest page change.

As I agree with Jeremy Carney that a long XPATH is not an option I found this way:
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//[@name="username"]').send_keys("username")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//[@name="password"]').send_keys("password")

That's literally an exact copy of my locators but XPath instead of CSS. If mine don't work then these won't work.
